# section appearing behind header

Tags: html, css, header, fluid

I'm following a tutorial at the minute to expand my design capabilities as my studies didn't cater for much web design.

For some reason my Section is appearing behind my Header and it's image and not below the Header section where it's placed.

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo" class="logo">
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Food Delivery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Cities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Welcome to my site.<br> Exciting opportunities.</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Call me</a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="section-features">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food.</h2>
            <p class="long-copy">

                Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
            </p>


        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                <p>
                    Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
                <p>
                    You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.

                </p>

            </div>
            </div>        

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-3-of-4">
                <h3>100% organic</h3>
                <p>
                    All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-4-of-4">
                <h3>Order anything</h3>
                <p>
                    We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
/*-------------------------------*/
/*BASIC SETUP */
/*-------------------------------*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    height: 100%;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*REUSABLE COMPONENTS */
/*-------------------------------*/

.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- HEADINGS --------*/

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 230%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

/*--------- BUTTONS --------*/

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    colour: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    margin-right: 15px; 
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #e67e22
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
    background-color: #cc6c15;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
       border: 1px solid #cc6c15;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #fff;

}


/*-------------------------------*/
/*HEADER */
/*-------------------------------*/

header {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img\hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    max-width: 90%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;

}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 85%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;

}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;

}
```

Fluid CSS

```
/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */

.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */


.span-2-of-2 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-2-of-2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */


.span-3-of-3 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-3-of-3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/*  GRID OF FOUR   ============================================================================= */


.span-4-of-4 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span-3-of-4 {
    width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-2-of-4 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-1-of-4 {
    width: 23.8%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-4-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF FIVE   ============================================================================= */


.span-5-of-5 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-4-of-5 {
    width: 79.68%; 
}

.span-3-of-5 {
    width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-2-of-5 {
    width: 39.04%;
}

.span-1-of-5 {
    width: 18.72%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-5-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF SIX   ============================================================================= */


.span-6-of-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-5-of-6 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span-4-of-6 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-3-of-6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

.span-2-of-6 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span-1-of-6 {
    width: 15.33%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-6-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}



/*  GRID OF SEVEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-7-of-7 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-6-of-7 {
    width: 85.48%;
}

.span-5-of-7 {
    width: 70.97%;
}

.span-4-of-7 {
    width: 56.45%;
}

.span-3-of-7 {
    width: 41.94%;
}

.span-2-of-7 {
    width: 27.42%;
}

.span-1-of-7 {
    width: 12.91%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-7-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF EIGHT   ============================================================================= */


.span-8-of-8 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-7-of-8 {
    width: 87.3%; 
}

.span-6-of-8 {
    width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-5-of-8 {
    width: 61.9%; 
}

.span-4-of-8 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-3-of-8 {
    width: 36.5%;
}

.span-2-of-8 {
    width: 23.8%; 
}

.span-1-of-8 {
    width: 11.1%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-8-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF NINE   ============================================================================= */


.span-9-of-9 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-8-of-9 {
    width: 88.71%;
}

.span-7-of-9 {
    width: 77.42%; 
}

.span-6-of-9 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-5-of-9 {
    width: 54.84%; 
}

.span-4-of-9 {
    width: 43.55%; 
}

.span-3-of-9 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span-2-of-9 {
    width: 20.97%; 
}

.span-1-of-9 {
    width: 9.68%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-9-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-10-of-10 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-9-of-10 {
    width: 89.84%;
}

.span-8-of-10 {
    width: 79.68%;
}

.span-7-of-10 {
    width: 69.52%; 
}

.span-6-of-10 {
    width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-5-of-10 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-4-of-10 {
    width: 39.04%; 
}

.span-3-of-10 {
    width: 28.88%;
}

.span-2-of-10 {
    width: 18.72%; 
}

.span-1-of-10 {
    width: 8.56%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-10-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF ELEVEN   ============================================================================= */

.span-11-of-11 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-10-of-11 {
    width: 90.76%;
}

.span-9-of-11 {
    width: 81.52%;
}

.span-8-of-11 {
    width: 72.29%;
}

.span-7-of-11 {
    width: 63.05%; 
}

.span-6-of-11 {
    width: 53.81%; 
}

.span-5-of-11 {
    width: 44.58%; 
}

.span-4-of-11 {
    width: 35.34%; 
}

.span-3-of-11 {
    width: 26.1%;
}

.span-2-of-11 {
    width: 16.87%; 
}

.span-1-of-11 {
    width: 7.63%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-11-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-10-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TWELVE   ============================================================================= */

.span-12-of-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-11-of-12 {
    width: 91.53%;
}

.span-10-of-12 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span-9-of-12 {
    width: 74.6%;
}

.span-8-of-12 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-7-of-12 {
    width: 57.66%; 
}

.span-6-of-12 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-5-of-12 {
    width: 40.73%; 
}

.span-4-of-12 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}

.span-3-of-12 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

.span-2-of-12 {
    width: 15.33%; 
}

.span-1-of-12 {
    width: 6.86%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-12-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-11-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-10-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this if it is fine for you:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    height: 100%;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*REUSABLE COMPONENTS */
/*-------------------------------*/

.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- HEADINGS --------*/

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 230%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

/*--------- BUTTONS --------*/

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    colour: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    margin-right: 15px; 
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #e67e22
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
    background-color: #cc6c15;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
       border: 1px solid #cc6c15;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #fff;

}


/*-------------------------------*/
/*HEADER */
/*-------------------------------*/

header {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img\hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}



 
.hero-text-box{margin:50px 0}
.hero-text-box h1 {color:#000000}

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;

}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 85%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;

}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;

}
/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */

.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */


.span-2-of-2 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-2-of-2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */


.span-3-of-3 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-3-of-3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/*  GRID OF FOUR   ============================================================================= */


.span-4-of-4 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span-3-of-4 {
    width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-2-of-4 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-1-of-4 {
    width: 23.8%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-4-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF FIVE   ============================================================================= */


.span-5-of-5 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-4-of-5 {
    width: 79.68%; 
}

.span-3-of-5 {
    width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-2-of-5 {
    width: 39.04%;
}

.span-1-of-5 {
    width: 18.72%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-5-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF SIX   ============================================================================= */


.span-6-of-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-5-of-6 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span-4-of-6 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-3-of-6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

.span-2-of-6 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span-1-of-6 {
    width: 15.33%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-6-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}



/*  GRID OF SEVEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-7-of-7 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-6-of-7 {
    width: 85.48%;
}

.span-5-of-7 {
    width: 70.97%;
}

.span-4-of-7 {
    width: 56.45%;
}

.span-3-of-7 {
    width: 41.94%;
}

.span-2-of-7 {
    width: 27.42%;
}

.span-1-of-7 {
    width: 12.91%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-7-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF EIGHT   ============================================================================= */


.span-8-of-8 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-7-of-8 {
    width: 87.3%; 
}

.span-6-of-8 {
    width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-5-of-8 {
    width: 61.9%; 
}

.span-4-of-8 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-3-of-8 {
    width: 36.5%;
}

.span-2-of-8 {
    width: 23.8%; 
}

.span-1-of-8 {
    width: 11.1%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-8-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF NINE   ============================================================================= */


.span-9-of-9 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-8-of-9 {
    width: 88.71%;
}

.span-7-of-9 {
    width: 77.42%; 
}

.span-6-of-9 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-5-of-9 {
    width: 54.84%; 
}

.span-4-of-9 {
    width: 43.55%; 
}

.span-3-of-9 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span-2-of-9 {
    width: 20.97%; 
}

.span-1-of-9 {
    width: 9.68%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-9-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-10-of-10 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-9-of-10 {
    width: 89.84%;
}

.span-8-of-10 {
    width: 79.68%;
}

.span-7-of-10 {
    width: 69.52%; 
}

.span-6-of-10 {
    width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-5-of-10 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-4-of-10 {
    width: 39.04%; 
}

.span-3-of-10 {
    width: 28.88%;
}

.span-2-of-10 {
    width: 18.72%; 
}

.span-1-of-10 {
    width: 8.56%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-10-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF ELEVEN   ============================================================================= */

.span-11-of-11 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-10-of-11 {
    width: 90.76%;
}

.span-9-of-11 {
    width: 81.52%;
}

.span-8-of-11 {
    width: 72.29%;
}

.span-7-of-11 {
    width: 63.05%; 
}

.span-6-of-11 {
    width: 53.81%; 
}

.span-5-of-11 {
    width: 44.58%; 
}

.span-4-of-11 {
    width: 35.34%; 
}

.span-3-of-11 {
    width: 26.1%;
}

.span-2-of-11 {
    width: 16.87%; 
}

.span-1-of-11 {
    width: 7.63%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-11-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-10-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TWELVE   ============================================================================= */

.span-12-of-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-11-of-12 {
    width: 91.53%;
}

.span-10-of-12 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span-9-of-12 {
    width: 74.6%;
}

.span-8-of-12 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-7-of-12 {
    width: 57.66%; 
}

.span-6-of-12 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-5-of-12 {
    width: 40.73%; 
}

.span-4-of-12 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}

.span-3-of-12 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

.span-2-of-12 {
    width: 15.33%; 
}

.span-1-of-12 {
    width: 6.86%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-12-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-11-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-10-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo" class="logo">
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Food Delivery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Cities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
      
    </header>

    <div class="section-features">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Welcome to my site.<br> Exciting opportunities.</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Call me</a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>
            <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food.</h2>
            <p class="long-copy">

                Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
            </p>


        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                <p>
                    Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
                <p>
                    You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.

                </p>

            </div>
            </div>        

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-3-of-4">
                <h3>100% organic</h3>
                <p>
                    All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-4-of-4">
                <h3>Order anything</h3>
                <p>
                    We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header should not have `position:fixed`. You can also remove the `top` and `left` properties.

It should look like this:

```
/*-------------------------------*/
/*HEADER */
/*-------------------------------*/

header {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img\hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's sorted it if I change the height of the header to fit the hero text box in and the percentage on the height of the hero textbox. Any idea why my background image isn't showing on my header either?